# Ubuntu 22.04 Software to neat and clean image like ClearScan etc

Tags: brightness

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. In android mobile there are many applications like ClearScan in which you just upload an image and it automatically adjust its brightness and contrast. Is there any software for Ubuntu 22.04 in which I just open the image run one command and it will make my image neat and clean.

Comment: I don't know of any particular such program that can be installed in Ubuntu, but you will find many such web-based programs with a google search.

Comment: It seems you can do this with gimp, but it needs a bit of work on your side to set up. https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Automate_Editing_in_GIMP/